# Shell script to automate scp command

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I have to move file from one server to the other server for which i am using

```
scp user@sourceservername:sourcefilepath user@destservername:destdirectory
```

when i execute this script it asks for password of both the source and destination. Can this scp command be included in a shell script such that the password is picked dynamically ? alongwith file name and file path ?

Comment: [Passwordless SSH](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) can help you here.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by generating private/public keys for both servers.

Use `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` later to copy your public key to both servers.

Steps:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id user@sourceservername
ssh-copy-id user@destservername
scp -3 user@sourceservername:sourcefilepath user@destservername:destdirectory
```

Notice the `-3` option, this will transfer the file from sourceservername to your local server and then to destservername. This way you will have only single pair of private/public keys.

Comment: Hi @krzyk - can u tell me the exact sequence and eact command ?